# Does Wendy eat air to help her with her power?

Tags: fairy-tail

Since she's a Dragon Slayer, she needs to eat her power to help her. So, if she ate air around non-polluted areas, she could use her wind power more often than Natsu or Gajeel. As said, if she were able to perform this eating process it would be pretty amazing.

So, does Wendy eat air to help her with her power?

Comment: I believe it has already been answered. The Fairy Tail Wiki confirms the fact as well.
http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Wendy_Marvell

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Carla said so (From *Fairy Tail* chapter 136, "Coffin")

[image: "What does she eat?" "Air"]

> Natsu : The "Sky Dragon Slayer". What does she eat?
>
> Carla : Air
>
> Natsu : Is it delicious?
>
> Carla : Yes...